# Metadata error in WCF web service hosted in SharePoint 2010

Tags: wcf, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I am having an issue with creating a web service and hosting it in SharePoint 2010. I've read every blog under the sun to no avail. When adding the deployed service as a reference to another project, I get the following error:

> There was an error downloading
>   'http://nb-dev-sp2010/_vti_bin/NBICWebServices/NBICAgencyService.svc'.
>   The request failed with an empty response. Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://nb-dev-sp2010/_vti_bin/NBICWebServices/NBICAgencyService.svc'.
>   The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by
>   a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error. If the service is defined in the current solution, try
>   building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I have the following as a web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NBICBinding">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="NBICWebServices.INBICAgencyService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/_vti_bin/NBICWebServices/NBICAgencyService.svc"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NBICBinding"
             contract="NBICWebServices.INBICAgencyService" name="NBICBindingAgency" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <!--
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/_vti_bin/NBICWebServices/NBICAgencyService.svc"
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NBICBinding"
             contract="NBICWebServices.INBICAgencyService" name="NBICBindingAgency" />
    </client>
    -->
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone see a problem here? Yes, I know I shouldn't have anonymous authentication on. I'll come back to that issue later on. :-)